# The "ExpoNativeModulesProxy" native module is not exported through NativeModules error after updating to sdk 34 expo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

Recently, I've updated my react native Expo app to use Expo sdk 34, and I am getting this error: `The "ExpoNativeModulesProxy" native module is not exported through NativeModules; verify that expo-react-native-adapter's native code is linked properly`.

I've used the [code-mod](https://www.npmjs.com/package/expo-codemod) that expo suggests in [their upgrading to sdk 34 docs](https://blog.expo.io/expo-sdk-34-is-now-available-4f7825239319), I've updated my expo-cli, node version and have switched from using npm to yarn, and am still seeing this error no matter what I try.

I am using this environment:

```
  Expo CLI 3.0.9 environment info:
    System:
      OS: macOS 10.14.6
      Shell: 5.3 - /bin/zsh
    Binaries:
      Node: 12.8.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
      Yarn: 1.17.3 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
      npm: 6.10.3 - /usr/local/bin/npm
      Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
    IDEs:
      Android Studio: 3.4 AI-183.6156.11.34.5692245
      Xcode: 10.3/10G8 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
    npmPackages:
      expo: ^34.0.1 => 34.0.4
      react: 16.8.3 => 16.8.3
      react-native: https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-34.0.0.tar.gz => 0.59.8
      react-navigation: ^2.18.2 => 2.18.3
    npmGlobalPackages:
      expo-cli: 3.0.9
```

In my `app.json` I am using `{"sdkVersion": "34.0.0"}` and my `package.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "test": "node ./node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --watchAll"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.4.4",
    "@expo/samples": "2.1.1",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^10.0.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.10.1",
    "@fortawesome/pro-light-svg-icons": "^5.10.1",
    "@fortawesome/pro-regular-svg-icons": "^5.10.1",
    "@fortawesome/pro-solid-svg-icons": "^5.10.1",
    "adm-zip": "^0.4.13",
    "babel-plugin-react-native-classname-to-style": "^1.2.2",
    "babel-plugin-react-native-platform-specific-extensions": "^1.1.1",
    "expo": "^34.0.1",
    "expo-asset": "~6.0.0",
    "expo-codemod": "^1.0.6",
    "expo-constants": "6.0.0",
    "expo-core": "^3.0.1",
    "expo-facebook": "^6.0.0",
    "expo-file-system": "~6.0.0",
    "expo-font": "^6.0.1",
    "expo-localization": "^6.0.0",
    "expo-react-native-adapter": "^3.0.1",
    "expo-web-browser": "6.0.0",
    "fastfall": "^1.5.1",
    "har-validator": "^5.1.3",
    "i18n-js": "^3.3.0",
    "i18next-conv": "^9.1.0",
    "jsc-android": "^236355.1.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "mobx": "^5.13.0",
    "mobx-react": "^5.4.4",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.26",
    "native-base": "^2.13.4",
    "plist": "^3.0.1",
    "progress": "^2.0.3",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-currency-formatter": "^1.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-i18next": "^10.11.5",
    "react-moment": "^0.8.4",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-34.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-actionsheet": "^2.4.2",
    "react-native-collapsible": "^1.5.1",
    "react-native-config": "^0.11.7",
    "react-native-fontawesome-pro": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-geocoding": "^0.3.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-google-places-autocomplete": "^1.3.9",
    "react-native-loading-spinner-overlay": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.24.0",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^6.1.0",
    "react-native-numeric-input": "^1.8.3",
    "react-native-picker-select": "^6.3.0",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^4.0.6",
    "react-native-svg": "~9.5.1",
    "react-native-svg-animated-linear-gradient": "^0.3.2",
    "react-native-web": "^0.11.4",
    "react-native-webview-messaging": "^1.2.3",
    "react-navigation": "^2.18.2",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "rn-webview": "^0.1.0",
    "validator": "^10.11.0",
    "validatorjs": "^3.15.1",
    "xcode": "^1.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.4.4",
    "babel-jest": "^23.6.0",
    "babel-preset-expo": "^6.0.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "^5.0.2",
    "jest-expo": "^34.0.0",
    "metro": "^0.55.0",
    "metro-bundler": "^0.22.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.51.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "react-native-sass-transformer": "^1.4.0",
    "react-native-typed-sass-transformer": "^0.11.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.8.6"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

To upgrade to expo sdk 34.0 I used the Expo instructions from their [release docs](https://blog.expo.io/expo-sdk-34-is-now-available-4f7825239319). Is there something I am doing wrong that may be causing this issue? If I checkout to a branch without the new sdk, I am not seeing this error.

Comment: Please refer https://forums.expo.io/t/the-exponativemodulesproxy-native-module-is-not-exported-through-nativemodules/26228/6

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a matter of setting something up.

You have already changed the `Expo` version from `^34.0.1` to `^34.0.4`.

But it's not changed, it's in your `package.json` file. I think we need to modify this.

1. rm -rf node_modules
2. change `"expo": "^34.0.1" => "expo": "^34.0.4"` in 
       `package.json`
3. `yarn install` or `npm install`
4. `expo start -c`

Comment: I tried updating both the `sdkVersion` and the `expo` version to `34.0.4` like you mentioned, but I got a different error:

`Warning: Problem validating app.json: Unable to perform cache refresh for /Users/espinozamaria/.expo/cache/schema-34.0.4.json: Error: Request failed with status code 404.
Error: Invalid sdkVersion. Valid options are 7.0.0, 8.0.0, 9.0.0, 10.0.0, 11.0.0, 12.0.0, 13.0.0, 14.0.0, 15.0.0, 16.0.0, 17.0.0, 18.0.0, 19.0.0, 20.0.0, 21.0.0, 22.0.0, 23.0.0, 24.0.0, 25.0.0, 26.0.0, 27.0.0, 28.0.0, 29.0.0, 30.0.0, 31.0.0, 32.0.0, 33.0.0, 34.0.0`

Comment: @MariaEspinoza  I'm sorry. It's my mistake. app.json includes a list of the versions. I modified the app.json change. updated my answer

Comment: Unfortunately, I am still getting the error after running those instructions in your answer

Comment: Could you try this? `expo install expo asset.`

Comment: I tried doing that, but still am not succeeding in getting rid of that error.

Comment: @MariaEspinoza It looks like you'd better ask the developer of Expo.

Comment: Thank you! I have posted but unfortunately have not heard back! I will keep trying to contact someone!